# Problem using BladeRF using two RX inputs

Tags: complex

I am working with BladeRF xA4.

I have a signal generator at 1.5GHz modulated with cos(2*pi*f_m*t)+j*sin(2*pi*f_m*t).
This generator is conected to a signal splitter. Next to the splitter two cables are connected to two inputs of the  BladeRF.

I acquired the waves with:

status = bladerf_sync_rx(dev_, &arr_, READ_SAMPLE_SIZE, &meta_, BLADERF_RX_TIMEOUT_MS);

meta_=NULL; //BLADERF_FORMAT_SC16_Q11

https://nuand.com/libbladeRF-doc/v2.2.1/group___s_t_r_e_a_m_i_n_g___f_o_r_m_a_t.html

arr_ is a an array of complexes int16. std::arraystd::complex<int16_t

arr_[0] , RX1

arr_[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxnZd.png)],  RX2

arr_[2],  RX1

I just plot the values and gives the plot in attach.

The signals instead to be equal, the second signal seems to have the I and Q exchanged.

Could anyone give a clue on this?

Thanks,

Luís Gonçalves

[image: Two RX Signals]

Comment: What is more worrying is that in RX2 the phase between I and Q is not pi/2. I'd say the problem is I/Q imbalance.

Comment: We have several boards and all have this problem.

Comment: You may have better luck here: https://www.nuand.com/forums/  Also, there's a ton of support info for these devices on their github wiki page: https://github.com/nuand/bladeRF/wiki

Comment: None of these problems are refered in it. And the forum is not accepting new posts for a long time.

Comment: RX1 seems that was aligned by factory (AD9361  align by Analog Devices or Nuand align with FPGA settings). RX2 seems completly unaligned.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of more help... I don't have a lot of experience with the BladeRF.